# Can I electrolyze saturated sodium hydroxide?

Tags: acid-base, electrolysis

Can I electrolyze saturated $\ce{NaOH(aq)}$? My guess is that I can't because in the aqueous solution, the concentration of $\ce{OH-}$ is too high and thus there isn't enough $\ce{H+}$ remaining.

Comment: Why, of course you can. There are never too few $\ce{H+}$. As soon as one $\ce{H+}$ discharges, another one steps in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At $T=25\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$, saturated sodium hydroxide solutions contain about $50\ \%$ sodium hydroxide. Hence, the concentration of $\ce{Na+}$ is about $c(\ce{Na+})=19\ \mathrm{mol\ l^{-1}}$ and the concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$ corresponds roughly to $\mathrm{pH\approx15}$, i.e. $c(\ce{H+})\approx10^{-15}\ \mathrm{mol\ l^{-1}}$ (neglecting activity coefficients).

The positive ions $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{H3O+}$ are attracted to the cathode. 
At the cathode, the redox potentials $E$ imply that, even under the given alkaline conditions, reduction of $\ce{H+}$ to $\ce{H2}$ is still preferred over reduction of $\ce{Na+}$ to $\ce{Na}$:

$$\begin{alignat}{3}
\ce{Na+ + e- \;&<=> Na}\qquad &&E^\circ = -2.713\ \mathrm V\qquad &&E&&=E^\circ+0.05916\ \mathrm{V}\times\log_{10} [\ce{Na+}]\\
& && && &&=-2.713\ \mathrm V+0.05916\ \mathrm{V}\times\log_{10} 19\\
& && && &&=-2.64\ \mathrm V\\[6pt]
\ce{2H+ + 2e- \;&<=> H2}\quad\quad &&E^\circ = +0.000\ \mathrm V\qquad &&E&&=E^\circ+0.05916\ \mathrm{V}\times\log_{10} [\ce{H+}]\\
& && && &&=0.000\ \mathrm V+0.05916\ \mathrm{V}\times\log_{10}(10^{-15})\\
& && && &&=-0.89\ \mathrm V
\end{alignat}$$

Therefore, the thermodynamically preferred reaction is the reduction of water to hydrogen according to
$$\ce{2H+ + 2e- -> H2 }$$
or in this case better (in view of the given alkaline conditions)
$$\ce{2H2O + 2e- -> H2 + 2OH- }$$

Nevertheless, under the given alkaline conditions, the concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$ is very low. The predominant positive ions are $\ce{Na+}$, which migrate to the cathode. Thus, especially when applying a high current density, the major part of the current of positive charges that reach the cathode is carried by $\ce{Na+}$. Therefore, $\ce{Na+}$ actually can be discharged at the cathode:
$$\ce{Na+ + e- -> Na}$$
The ratio of discharged $\ce{Na+}$ to $\ce{H+}$ also depends on the cathode material. For some materials, the reduction of $\ce{H+}$ to $\ce{H2}$ is kinetically inhibited, which results in a significant overpotential.

However, any generated $\ce{Na}$ immediately reacts with water (except when a mercury cathode is used): 
$$\ce{2Na + 2H2O -> 2Na+ + H2 + 2OH- }$$

Therefore, the net reaction is again the above-mentioned reduction of $\ce{H2O}$ to $\ce{H2}$. The $\ce{Na+}$ ions act as electrolyte and might be considered to act as a catalyst:

$$\begin{align}
\ce{2Na+ + 2e- &-> 2Na}\\
\ce{2Na + 2H2O &-> 2Na+ + H2 + 2OH- }\\
\hline\ce{2H2O + 2e- &-> H2 + 2OH- }
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Re:"However, any generated Na immediately reacts with water" - Is that true when potential is still applied to the electrode? It certainly would be true if electrode was tuned off. // I remember doing copper plating on a Pt electrode for an anal chem class. You had to keep the potential on until after you removed the electrode from the solution to keep the Cu from dissolving back into the solution.

Comment: @MaxW Yes, the applied potential affects the remobilization of substances that have been deposited on the cathode. (I had to consider this effect when making electrodepositions of actinoids for alpha spectrometry.) But in case of sodium, I guess (considering its reactivity and standard potential), it would be difficult to completely prevent the oxidation of metallic sodium in aqueous solutions.